# emacs term-mode redraws prompt when backspacing inside executables

Tags: bash, terminal, emacs, terminal-emulator

I am reliant on emacs (version 24.4.1 on Debian) `term` and `ansi-term` modes. They normally work just like xTerm for me, but when running an interactive program that has a prompt (like the node.js prompt, or the mongoDB prompt), deleting a character makes the entire prompt redraw inline.

For example, when I open the node app and type `TEXT` followed by a single backspace, I see

```
jim@achileus:~$ node                                                                  
> TEXT> TEX
```

and when I type `LONGER STRING` followed by 13 backspaces I see

```
jim@achileus:~$ node                                                                  
> LONGER STRING> LONGER STRIN> LONGER STRI> LONGER STR> LONGER ST> LONGER S> LONGER > LONGER> LONGE> LONG> LON> LO> L>
```

This error does not occur in emacs `shell` but I don't want to use it.

Any insight as to why this is happening, or any clues on how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know the answer, but it sounds like a terminal configuration issue, so I'll suggest checking this in case it's relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22091145/324105

Comment: Do you use something like elscreen?

Comment: Having the same problem

Comment: Could it be by any chance related to this: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/9871/extended-cursor-movement-in-terminal-emulator-cha-and-others/10698#10698

Comment: I install `emacs-snapshot` (the newest development release of emacs), and the problem gone.